# Can I use a specific bit version (32 or 64) of java for compilation through the terminal?

Tags: java, javac

Here are some details about my system:

- Windows 7 (64-Bit)
- JDK 1.8.0_05 (64-Bit)
- JDK 1.7.0_51 (32-Bit)
- Eclipse - Luna 4.4.0 (64-Bit)

Although my eclipse uses the 64-bit version of Java, I want to compile a Java program using the 32-bit version through the terminal.

Any suggestions how I can do that?

Comment: You could reference the full path to the 32 bit javac, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\javac` or whatever the path is on your machine. Note that a 32 bit javac and a 64 bit javac both produce bytecode that can be run with either a 32 bit or 64 bit JVM - and at least for the same javac version, they should produce identical bytecode too.

Comment: The generated bytecode should be the same no matter if you compile with 32 or 64 bit java. But if you compile with java 7/8 then it might be different.

Comment: there's no point doing that. Java bytecode is cross platform and can run anywhere regardless of the compiler

Answer (score 2):

If you find that the Windows or Linux or Mac or 32-bit or 64-bit compiler produces a different output, this is most likely a bug (unless the compiler runs out of memory)  Note: Eclipse has it's own compilers and it might generate different `.class` files.  Usually this doesn't matter however when it does it can lead to subtle inconsistencies.  I would make sure you always use the Oracle or IBM compiler if you can to avoid these issues.

However, you can specify the bit-ness in the same way you specify the version by setting the PATH or using the whole path when you run it.  If you use an IDE, this is what it does for you, and many, many other things.

Comment: Actually I'm calling the java applet inside the javascript. My browser (Chrome) only supports the 32-bit version of java. When I compiled the java file using the 64-bit version , the javascript code refused to take the .class file and displayed "Unsupported major.minor version 51.0" However when I compiled the same file using the 32-bit version , it worked fine.

Comment: The problem is setting up the path again and again. If I put the 32-bit version in the path , my eclipse does'nt work , If I put the 64-bit version I can't compile the code with 32-bit version. I'm looking for a solution that let me compile my code with whatever version i want.

Comment: Your 64 bit version is compiling for a newer version of java than your 32 bit jvm supports. I suggest you make your 64-bit and 32 bit jvms the same or use a build tools which controls the target version. As the 32 bit version won't compile the code I suggest uprating it to match the version which will.